# jQuery Ligthbox open and close instantly

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I have a function to erase some commerce from the database, I want the confirmation to appeared in a lightbox. It does open in a lightbox but it close almost instantly =/

jQuery:

```
    $('a#MontrerSuppression').click(function(){

    $('#BackgroundSuppression,#Suppression').fadeIn('fast');

});

$('a#CacherSuppression').click(function(){

    $('#BackgroundSuppression,#Suppression').fadeOut('fast');

});
```

php/html:

```
<a href='myaccount.php?IDCommerce=<?php echo $Commerce['IDCommerce'];?>' id="MontrerSuppression">Supprimer Commerce</a>
```

css:

BackgroundSuppression{width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top:0; left: 0; background-color: #999; opacity: 0.5; z-index: 1; display: none;}

Suppression{position: absolute; width: 375px; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #000; padding: 20px 20px 10px 10px; top: 50%; 
            margin-top: -130px; left:50%; margin-left: -250px; z-index: 2; display: none; text-align: center;}

The form:

```
            <div id="Suppression">
            <a href="#" id="CacherSuppression"><strong>×</strong></a>

            <?php supprimerCommerce(); ?>

            <form method="POST" action="myaccount.php">
                <p>Êtes vous sur de vouloir supprimer votre commerce?</br>Une fois supprimer les informations seront perdu à jamais.</p>
                <input type="submit" name="Confirmer" value="Oui"/>
                <input type="submit" name="Annuler" value="Annuler"/>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Think the problem is on the way I "link" the html link to the jQuery function but can't figure out what is the proper way to do it.

Really appreciat if someone could give me some help

Comment: I see nothing wrong, can you show us the #BackgroundSuppression #Suppression code?

Comment: sure, but it's only css.

Comment: I think Bouillou meant the html with those id's. Are you using jquery to control anything else?

Comment: Ah ok ok. No, just that. The backgroundsuppression is just an empty div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dMpNE/) and let me know if it is OK for you

**EDIT**

OK, I understand. The fact is that the onclick event is overwrited by the href link.
Try this fiddle version : http://jsfiddle.net/dMpNE/1/

Comment: With no link works great. But when I add the link, same problem =/

Comment: ANd with the new fiddle version?

Answer (score 0):

I hope for `a#MontrerSuppression` contains an href attribute. So to remove its from clicked try the following.

```
$('a#MontrerSuppression').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#BackgroundSuppression,#Suppression').fadeIn('fast');
});
```